# Metric on the embedded hyperboloid in five-dimensional Minkowski space

Tags: differential-geometry, physics, mathematical-physics

I have an explicit parametrisation of a one-sheeted hyperboloid in the five-dimensional Minkowski space, namely:

$$Z_{0}=-l \cdot \cot(\tau)$$

$$Z_{a}=\frac{l}{\sin(\tau)}\omega_{a}, \quad a=1,\ldots,4$$

Where the $\omega_{a}$ represent the coordinates that embed a unit three sphere into $\Bbb R^4$ and satisfy $\omega_{a} \omega_{a}=1$. In the ambient space we have the metric:

$$ds^2=-dZ_{0}^2+dZ_{1}^2+dZ_{2}^2+dZ_{3}^2+dZ_{4}^2.$$

Now I am trying to verify that for the coordinates above the metric takes the form:

> $$ds^2=\frac{l^2}{\sin^2(\tau)}(-d \tau^2 +d\Omega_{3}^2)$$

Where $d\Omega_{3}^2$ denotes the metric of the unit three-sphere.

I am extremly thankful for every answer, comment or idea!

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Some parts in your question are a bit confusing. I will try to help though. $ds^2$ is a metric on a $5$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime (in physics notations, they would write this as $4 + 1$). In the last equation, $ds^2$ is a metric on a $4$-dimensional spacetime. So you are probably restricting the ambient metric in your last equation.

Comment: It seems to me what you need to do is express $ds^2$ in new coordinates. Originally, it is expressed in terms of $Z_0, Z_1, \ldots Z_4$ and you would like to express it in terms of the new coordinates $\tau, \omega_1, \ldots, \omega_4$. It seems to me that $l$ is just a scaling constant. So essentially, you need to use the chain rule. Did you try the calculation?

Comment: @Malkoun First of all let me thank you for your comment. Yes, I tried to do the calculation but I was confused by a few things. Namely when we have $Z_{0}$ constant I see that its differential vanishes. and when the $\omega_{a}$ are the usual hyperspherical coordinates, I don't see why there are no derivatives of $\frac{l}{sin(\tau)}$ involved. Maybe I made some mistakes doing the calculations, but since I haven't found any yet, I'm asking the question. Maybe you can help to sketch them...

Comment: All right, I will write an answer for you.

Comment: Please edit the post to make it clear that the question actually is related to the hyperboloid with one sheet of unit spacelike vectors in $5$-dimensional Minkowski spacetime (instead of $Z_0 = const$, which, as you noted, does not lead to the sought-after metric). This will help future readers. For instance, you can add "Edit:..." at the end of your post. Thank you. It was a fun little question.

Comment: I incorporated the edit that @Malkoun: recommended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us set $l=1$. One can reinsert the right power of $l$ at the end, as it is nothing but a scaling constant.

Let me first correct that the problem actually concerns the hyperboloid with one sheet $M$ of all unit spacelike vectors in Minkowski $5$-dimensional spacetime, namely the vectors $Z^a$ satisfying $Z^a Z_a = 1$, where I am implicitly using Einstein's summation convention over indices $a$ going from $0$ to $4$, and I have used the Minkowski metric to lower the index of the second $Z$.

The problem is essentially a change of coordinate problem. Let us delve into the details. We have

$$dZ_0 = - \csc^2(\tau)d\tau,$$ which gives $$dZ_0^2 = \csc^4(\tau)d\tau^2.$$

Similarly,

$$dZ_i = -\csc(\tau)\cot(\tau) \omega_i d\tau + \csc(\tau) d\omega_i,$$ which, upon squaring, gives
$$dZ_i^2 = \csc^2(\tau)\cot^2(\tau)\omega_i^2d\tau^2 + \csc^2(\tau)d\omega_i^2 
- 2 \csc^2(\tau)\cot(\tau) \omega_i d\omega_i d\tau.$$ Note that $\sum_{i=1}^4 \omega_i^2 = 1$, which implies, upon differentiating, that $\sum_{i=1}^4 \omega_i d\omega_i = 0$. This implies that after taking a summation for $i$ going from $1$ to $4$, the last term in the formula for $dZ_i^2$ above vanishes.

Hence the metric on the $4$-dimensional hyperboloid with one sheet $M$ becomes in the new coordinates:
$$ ds^2 = -(\csc^4(\tau) - \csc^2(\tau)\cot^2(\tau))d\tau^2 + \csc^2(\tau) 
\sum_{i=1}^4 d\omega_i^2.$$
After factoring out $\csc^2(\tau)$ and using the trigonometric identity $\csc^2(\tau)-\cot^2(\tau) = 1$, one gets the sought-after expression, albeit with $l$ set to $1$ (see my remark at the beginning of this post).

Comment: This is a very good answer. I have a small question, though. I understand that the expression for $Z_0$ comes from differentiating $Z_0=-\cot(\tau)$. Where does the expression for $Z_i$ come from? EDIT: oh sorry, now I see, it is just a differentiation of $Z_i=\frac{1}{\sin \tau} \omega_i$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, thank you for the "very good answer" part.

Comment: I think there is a typo in the formula for $dZ_i^2$; the $d\tau$ is missing. The last summand should contain $d\tau d\omega_i+d \omega_i d\tau$ instead of $d\omega_i$, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, yes you are right. I copied wrong from my notebook. It is fixed now (by the way I am implicitly using the symmetric tensor product in my notation).